# Is it safe to disable InnoDB doublewrite buffering when setting Innodb_page_size = filesystem page size?

Tags: mysql, innodb

As I understand, doublewrite buffering is needed to avoid partial write, because Innodb_page_size default is 16K, while filesystem page size normallly is 4K; I wonder if I set "Innodb_page_size =  filesystem page size", then I could disable  InnoDB doublewrite buffering safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background info...  The "torn page" problem occurs when part of an InnoDB block is written to disk, but the physical write died before writing all the low level (usually 512-byte) blocks.  This leads to an unreadable block for InnoDB.  The double-write buffer, and its extra write, makes it possible to recover from a torn page.

The hardware needs to "guarantee" atomic writes of 16KB.  FusionIO is the only drive that I know of to provide that guarantee.  And that gives them a advantage by saying that you can turn off double-writes.

RAID controllers with a battery-backed-write-cache *should* be able to provide such a guarantee, but it is unclear whether the OS confuses the issue.  But, then, writes are virtually free, so turning off double-write does not matter much.

I hesitate to say yes or no to your question because I don't know what is underneath the "filesystem".  It may turn the InnoDB block into multiple 512-byte disk writes, thereby still allowing torn pages.

O_DIRECT is a related topic to look at.

Setting innodb_page_size to 4K has other issues (even if you could get the drive to play nice) --

- Records are limited to about 2000 bytes instead of about 8000.
- You are asking for more I/Os.  This may be good or bad.  Random point queries of small rows will work faster with 4K blocks; most other situations *may* work slower.

Comment: Shannon also has SSD products that provide atomic-write

Comment: @leafonsword -- please provide a web page explaining Shannon's solution.

Comment: In  DTCC 2015, shannon have a presentation introducing their PCIe -- http://wenku.it168.com/d_001613581.shtml

Comment: I can't read Chinese, but the English titles make it sound like Shannon has addressed not just torn pages, but other I/O needs of InnoDB.  Does it do compression, too?

Comment: It didn't mention compression feature in this presentation; I think its atomic-write is very exciting because it works on all file system format, while FusionIO needs DFS~

Comment: I'll wait for a third party to validate the numerous claims in Shannon's list.

Comment: If a disk is not fusion-io or raid,  and disk block is 16K,innodb_page_size is also 16K; In this situation, will it be safe to disable double write?

Comment: Is it _really_ 16K on the disk?  Or is it pretending, and still writing a bunch of 512-byte sectors on the drive?  Virident, for example had a capacitor to 'guarantee' that any write that was started would be finished.  Since SSDs have other stuff that needs to persist, there is a good chance that all of them can write 16K atomically.  But -- see if they are willing to claim it.

Comment: This is my question: linux's ext4 filesystem's default disk block size is 4k, but disk sector size is 512-byte; So for normal sas magnetometric disk, does this mean even normal file operation, linux couldn't avoid partial write in ext4?

Comment: Valid question.  I don't know enough about ext4 (or any other fs) to answer at that level.  I would _guess_ that "consumer grade" hardware could have partial writes, but "enterprise" grade might protect against that.  It's probably the disk controller's choice, not ext4.  Well, some filesystems have "journalling", which may protect you.  (InnoDB's "doublewrite buffer" protects at the InnoDB level.)

Comment: Some disk have sector sizes that are 4K, rather than 512 byte. The unbuffered single sector write (of course on proper 4K boundaries) is atomic. So with such disk, and 4KB innodb pages, and O_DIRECT on Linux, and with innodb_flush_neighbors=0, disabling doublewrite buffering should be safe.